# An error occured while attempting to process /ajax/ajax_facets/refresh:$.blockUI is not a function

Tags: views, ajax, search

[Ajax facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_facets) work but I get an error "**An error occured while attempting to process /ajax/ajax_facets/refresh:$.blockUI is not a function**" when I click on ajax links with checkboxes for the facets for the first time.

I am using search api views as per mentioned in the project description
You can check the error in the screenshot attached
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was occuring due to conflict with other module [Ajax Screen Lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_screen_lock)

Disabling it solves the problem.